# Disable right-click menu in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm writing aWebGL game and want to use right-click as a control. However, it throws up a menu. Is it possible to disable that? I've tried

```
} 
else if (event.which == 2 || event.which == 3) 
{
    doRightClickControl();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    return false;
}
```

---

Thanks dknaack for the hint. I got it to work like this:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using jQuery for this purpose only is overkill. This will do the trick:

```
(function () {
  var blockContextMenu, myElement;

  blockContextMenu = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  };

  myElement = document.querySelector('#myElement');
  myElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', blockContextMenu);
})();
```

myElement can be replaced with window.

Comment: I actually ended up doing something like this, without pulling in JQuery.

Comment: And for the casual readers coming from Google, please don't do this unless you have a good reason. [Your users may despise your site](http://superuser.com/questions/279166/how-do-i-set-google-chrome-to-not-allow-javascript-to-hijack-my-right-click-menu).

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome 66

Comment: Just what I wanted!  I combined it into a single statement and added in that holding shift would let it pass through again.  --- document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('contextmenu', function (evt) {
  if(!evt.shiftKey){
   evt.preventDefault();
  }
 });

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<title>disable rightclick menu - LabLogic</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.oncontextmenu=RightMouseDown;
  document.onmousedown = mouseDown; 

  function mouseDown(e) {
      if (e.which==3) {//righClick
      alert("Disabled - do whatever you like here..");
   }
}
function RightMouseDown() { return false;}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested in chrome 17, works with other new browsers as well

Comment: Worked fine in firefox and chrome but not working in internet explorer 8..tested it. Its showing Errors on Page and then error is : which is null or not an object..Please look into it..thanks btw :)