# oncontectmenu - Disable chrome right-click menu and call a different function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am interested in eliminating chrome's right click menu on a right click and execute a new function.

Currently, I do the following:

new_tab_li.oncontextmenu = myFunction;

This excutes "myFunction" but, it also opens up chrome's right click menu.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789843/disable-right-click-menu-in-chrome?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable right-click context-menu in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `return false;` inside your custom function

```
function myFunction{
  // Your code
  return false;
}
```